# SYB Libraries functions

Tags: haskell, scrap-your-boilerplate

I've been working with some scrap-your-boilerplate functions for a while. Nevertheless, I tried to compile a module that imports `Data.Data` and `Data.Typeable`, though some functions like `everywhere` and `mkT` could not be found by the compiler. Where are these functions in the new versions of GHC?

Comment: for the record, what version of GHC are you using?

Comment: The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`mkT`](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=mkT) and [`everywhere`](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=everywhere) are part of the `syb` package. I don't know that they've ever been part of base.